# Image File Download issue in ionic for iOS platform

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework

I am trying to download some image files and store it for offline accessibility purpose of the app using Ionic framework. I have used two Cordova plugins named "**Cordova-plugin-file**" and "**Cordova-plugin-file transfer**". My code works on Android but faces a strange issue in iOS platform.

> Error in Success callbackId: FileTransfer552364304 : TypeError: null
>   is not an object (evaluating 'result.lengthComputable'),
>   callbackFromNativecordova.js

Sometimes the code works, sometimes it throws me this error. Also I cannot access the error from my javascript code. Can anyone help? The code snippet is given below:

```
downloadImage: function(url, fileName) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
                fs.root.getDirectory(
                    LOCAL_STORAGE_KEYS.app, {
                        create: true
                    },
                    function(dirEntry) {
                        // console.log(arguments);
                        dirEntry.getFile(
                            fileName, {
                                create: true,
                                exclusive: false
                            },
                            function(fe) {
                                console.log(arguments);

                                var p = fe.toURL();
                                console.log("In service the url path:", p);
                                fe.remove();
                                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                                console.log('File Transfer instance:',ft);
                                ft.download(
                                    encodeURI(url),
                                    p,
                                    function(entry) {
                                        console.log('In service the entry callback:',entry);
                                        if (entry && entry.toURL) {
                                            deferred.resolve(entry.toURL());
                                        } else {
                                            deferred.resolve();
                                        }
                                    },
                                    function(err) {
                                        console.log('Getting rejected:',err);
                                        deferred.reject(err);
                                    },
                                    false,
                                    null
                                );
                            },
                            function() {
                                deferred.reject(new Error('get file  failed'));
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            },
            function() {
                deferred.reject(new Error('get directory failed'));
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Can anyone please help? I am really stuck at this.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same issue on iOS too....works fine on Android though.